# reset or overwrite value of integer

Tags: c++, arrays, char, integer

I am trying to create a function that properly spaces a competition bracket. I've written this so far:

Everything works but everytime I call the function into main (where I print out the bracket), it only couts the correct spacing for shuffledteamnames[0] and any other team names with the same char length as index 0. To fix this issue I just need to get int u to reset everytime I call the function in main so it couts different amounts of spaces rather than just the first u. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's `shuffledteamnames` and where and how It is declared?? (comments don't suffice here, be precise please!)

Comment: it is a global variable char shuffledteamnames[8][80]

Comment: put the last for loop in first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the `makeSpace()` function to print the appropriate amount of spaces following the team name, then you can write it as follows, making sure that you pass the team name to the function each time:

```
// earlier code
makeSpace(shuffledteamnames[0]);

// new version of makeSpace()
void makeSpace(const char *teamName)
{
    int len = strlen(teamName);
    int u   = 11 - len;

    for (int k = 0; k < u; k++)
    {
        cout << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: ive tried that but what it still creates a spacing error. essentially it is running both loops 8 * u times, couting that many spaces

Comment: to give a little more detail, I am trying to fit a team name into a box that is 11 char wide. I print out my team name then subtract the str length and cout the left over spots as spaces so it makes everything alligned

Comment: can you provide the expected output?

Comment: http://imgur.com/AJsZwPy,

Comment: if trojans is in the first index than all other team names with char length 7 couts the correct amount of spaces, also it does not have to be centered

Comment: I'm still not quite following what you expect your code to do. Are you trying to print a team name, and then fill the unused remaining space (out of 11 characters) with spaces? Maybe if you write it pseudocode?

Comment: yeah exactly what im trying to do

Comment: Okay, then see my answer now. I just print the team name before the loop that prints spaces.

Comment: ahhh i see what youre getting at, but thats not quite it. i added my function for my bracket, and basically im already couting the team name within that function. I then call that function to get the proper spacing. sorry for the vagueness so far im just a beginner, but i still really appreciate the help

Comment: Ok I took one final stab based on the code that you posted. It should produce the result you're looking for.

Comment: wow thank you. took me awhile to see what you did there, as I'm still very iffy on pointers, but i get it now. thank you so much!